# Django insert image into content

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I'm looking for a way to insert images into a TextField content in Django that works in the Admin side as well as at the user end(non-Admin). I am looking for a simple 'browse' function to insert images from the user's local drives.

I am using TinyMCE for entering contents, but all the plugins I found to upload images through 'browsing' have some form of PHP scripts. I am looking for a non-PHP solution as I'm limited to using Python and Django for the web environment.

Appreciate any pointers or references provided.Thanks!

Comment: Django-tinyMce has an option for Uploading Images just add "image" to theme buttons

Answer (score 1):

By editing the config of TinyMce you can upload images just as you edit content

```
tinyMCE.init({
             #add
              theme_advanced_buttons1: "image"
```

in **function initMCE()**

Comment: i am not sure if this is what the asker requested

Comment: thanks for your input but the default 'image' plugin does not come with a browse function

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to give https://github.com/TigorC/django-redactorjs a try: it is not based on tinymce, but redactorjs is also nice (and is much cleaner in my opinion, but I'm sure some people prefer tinyMCE) and it has image uploader built-in.